# how to make the print answer does not repeat the word everytime the answer come out?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this program:

```
a = []
num = input('Enter numbers *Separate by using commas:')
num = num.split(",")
for i in num:
    a.append(i)

num = list(map(int,a))

print('~~Output~~')

for x in num:
    if x >= 10:
        print('Values >= 10 :',x,end = '~')
```

and it came out like this:

```
Enter numbers *Separate by using commas:12,1,10,5
~~Output~~
Values >= 10 : 12~Values >= 10 : 10~
>>>
```

how do I make it so that it print like this:

```
Enter numbers *Separate by using commas:12,1,10,5
~~Output~~
Values >= 10 : ~12~10~
>>>
```

thanks.

is it like this:

```
a = []
num = input('Enter numbers *Separate by using commas:')

for i in num:
    if i >= 10:
        a.append(i)
        print('~' + '~'.join(a) + '~')
```

it will print:

```
if i >= 10:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
>>>
```

I don't really understand....sorry...is there a simpler one using this for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant to print the label before the values? Not part of every value?

```
print('Values >= 10 :', end ='') 
for x in num:
    if x >= 10:
        print(x,end = '~')
```

Your second error is that you are iterating over a string... You forgot to split the commas, and map the strings to integers

Comment: can you explain why does the print for values>= 10 is above the for loop

Comment: Because you don't want it to be printed every time you loop

Answer (score 0):

Add the numbers into a list and then print them.

```
numbersHigher = []
for x in num:
    if x >= 10:
        numbersHigher.append(x)
```

Zach King suggested list comprehension(Google it if you want to know more)

```
numbersHigher = [x for x in num if x >= 10]
```

Then you print it once after the loop.
It happens because there might be 2 numbers and you print twice because x is higher than 1- 2 times.
EDIT:
To make the last print like you want you can do:

```
import string
print('~' + '~'.join(numbersHigher) + '~')
```

Comment: More concisely: `numbersHigher = [x for x in num if x >= 10]`

Comment: @ZachKing, I agree you can do it in that way too but since he is a started it would be better to do it the "explicit" way (Not with list comprehension)
Added your response too Zach.